# Convert Sql-Server DateTime to M/D/Y Format

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql-server

I want to convert a sql-server dateTime variable to MDY format. 
Here is what it looks like : 
2016-12-30 21:34:56.840

I would like it to look like : 12/30/2016

Comment: Try this:                                                                                               SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), cast('2016-12-30 21:34:56.840' as date), 101)

--output: 12/30/2016

Answer (score 0):

You can convert using the 106 style from SQL Server

```
SELECT replace(convert(NVARCHAR, getdate(), 106), ' ', '/')
```